# Disable form edit in jqgrid based on condition

Tags: jqgrid

I am using form edit in JQGRID. The JQGRID has a field called "Type" and other fields. 
When the user clicks edit button and if the selected value of type is "X" it should not allow to Edit. A Message should be displayed "Record cannot be edited".

I have seen examples to disable certain fields from editing in inline-editing

I tried this as well

[Edit rows based on condition in JQGRID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537146/edit-rows-based-on-condition-in-jqgrid)

can please help me. Thanks for your time

Comment: show code of edit options and column model of Type field

Comment: @janina http://jsfiddle.net/VTL4x/  I need to edit only if the "Shipped Via" field is "TNT" all others should be disabled for editing but should be displayed for other operations

Comment: your demo always selecting "TNT" by default,make it as it selects the currect value that is in the shipped via

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I found this and it solved the problem Thanks janina  for your help and time

And special  thanks to @oleg who had provided this solution

[jqgrid: how to set toolbar options based on column value in row selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373693/jqgrid-how-to-set-toolbar-options-based-on-column-value-in-row-selected/5376355#5376355)